# Why do I get no products when use pre_get_posts in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

is there any known reason why I get 'no products found' when use `pre_get_posts`

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rc_modify_query_get_design_projects' );
function rc_modify_query_get_design_projects( $product ) {
  global $wp_query;
     $product->set('post_type', 'product_variation');
}
```

I'm using `pre_get_posts` to modify main wpquery to get variable products as single products because plugin filters only work with main wpquery if I'm right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would do this? This will show only product variations on Archive pages (shop,categories,etc).  WooCommerce has `woocommerce_product_query` it acts the same as pre_get_posts but is for the product loop.  You don't need globals to be passed.  The query is already passed.

```
function so_60561772_product_query( $q ){ 
    $q->set( 'post_type', 'product_variation'); 
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'so_60561772_product_query' );
```

Comment: oh, I see, tried that, does the job! Great, thank you! But I'am still getting no-products-found on some pages but on other pages i get variable products:
Here (https://woocommerce-271893-1183903.cloudwaysapps.com/wollbettdecke/) i've set `$q->set( 'post_type', array('product', 'product_variation'));` and I'm getting only products, not variations 
but here I get variations right: https://woocommerce-271893-1183903.cloudwaysapps.com/winterbettdecke/

First one is product_category and the second one is listing by pa_attribute

Comment: If you want to phase this new question to a question... Tag me in a comment and I will look at it with you.